# Throughput improvement for Billion row insert to CloudSql

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a table which has about 600 million to 1 billion rows per day. i.e. 30m- 40m recs/hour

1 hour's worth of data inserts to CloudSql is taking about 35 mins avg.
What can i do to improve this performance wise, configuration wise, DB-design wise and/or any other things we might miss?

Data is being insert from project 1 to project 2, reading parquet files from GCS, convert them using DataProc cluster in a format acceptable to CloudSql and then inserted into CloudSql, given the limitations mysql (aka CloudSql) naturally imposes on large volume inserts anyways.
I am using a 20 Master node cluster. My target MySql instance is a 52 GB, 8 vCPU CloudSql instance with 600 GB SSD storage with innodb_write_io_threads set to 12. Database version is MySQL 5.7.

How can i possibly increase the throughput i.e. 1 hour's data (35 million recs) is taking about 35-40 minutes? CPU usage is at 90% and memory usage is at 80%

Comment: What is the machine type and version of your Dataproc cluster? Is the cluster primarily being used for converting data read from GCS to format supported by CloudSql, or is it doing anything else?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that CloudSQL and MySQL designed for this use case, for fully managed big data analytics on GCP you should use fully managed cloud data warehouse - [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery) instead.

Datproc Spark is easily integrated with BigQuery via [Spark BigQuery connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example).